# C# filestream, file cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, webserver

I have the following code acting as a controller on my .net core webapi:

```
public IActionResult ViewClip(string id)
        {
            filestream = new FileStream($"Clips/{id}.mp4", FileMode.Open);
            var response = Response;
            var length = filestream.Length;
            var range = response.HttpContext.GetRanges(length);

            if (IsRangeRequest(range))
            {
                response.StatusCode = 206;

                if (!IsMultipartRequest(range))
                {
                    response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes {range.Ranges.First().From}-{range.Ranges.First().To}/{length}");
                }

                foreach (var rangeValue in range.Ranges)
                {
                    if (IsMultipartRequest(range)) 
                    {
                        response.WriteAsync($"--<qwe123>--");
                        response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
                        response.WriteAsync($"Content-type: video/mp4");
                        response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
                        response.WriteAsync($"Content-Range: bytes {range.Ranges.First().From}-{range.Ranges.First().To}/{length}");
                        response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    WriteDataToResponseBody(rangeValue, response);

                    if (IsMultipartRequest(range))
                    {
                        response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }

                if (IsMultipartRequest(range))
                {
                    response.WriteAsync($"--<qwe123>--");
                    response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                filestream.Dispose();
                return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"Clips/{id}.mp4"), "application/octet-stream", $"{id}.mp4", enableRangeProcessing: true);
            }
            else
            {
                filestream.Dispose();
                return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"Clips/{id}.mp4"), "application/octet-stream", $"{id}.mp4", enableRangeProcessing: true);
            }
        }
        private bool IsMultipartRequest(RangeHeaderValue range)
        {
            return range != null && range.Ranges != null && range.Ranges.Count > 1;
        }

        private bool IsRangeRequest(RangeHeaderValue range)
        {
            return range != null && range.Ranges != null && range.Ranges.Count > 0;
        }
        public static void WriteDataToResponseBody(RangeItemHeaderValue rangeValue, HttpResponse response)
        {
            var startIndex = rangeValue.From ?? 0;
            var endIndex = rangeValue.To ?? 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            long totalToSend = endIndex - startIndex;
            int count = 0;

            long bytesRemaining = totalToSend + 1;
            response.ContentLength = bytesRemaining;

            filestream.Seek(startIndex, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            while (bytesRemaining > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (bytesRemaining <= buffer.Length)
                        count = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRemaining);
                    else
                        count = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (count == 0)
                        return;

                    response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, count);

                    bytesRemaining -= count;
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    response.Body.FlushAsync();
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    response.Body.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, When I send a request to this endpoint, the server throws the error "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file '...Clips\8ViAhBctO.mp4' because it is being used by another process.'.

I've tried disposing the filestream before returning the file to the user, which seems to have had no effect. FYI this was on windows.

Comment: `FileResult` can accept FileStream as its first parameter. Try use that, and together use `using FileStream fileStream = ...`, and don't dispose manually. Just let `using` handle it. If problem persists, let us know which line did the IOException happen.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang receiving the same error after returning filestream and implementing using. exception happens on line 13, which contains the using statement.             using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream($"Clips/{id}.mp4", FileMode.Open))

Comment: If you just want to get the file length, consider using `new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length`

Comment: `filestream` needs a `using` to dispose it correctly.